# How to disable clang warnings for protobuf generation in CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to Cmake/protobuf domain

In my CMakeList.txt I have
`set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=google-*,cppcoreguidelines-*")`
for linter warnings.

Also I include Catkinized gRPC Package for protobuf

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS grpc)

generate_proto(......)
```

When I compile this project, I am seeing a lot of warnings for `file_name.pb.cc` files

Is there any way to disable clang linter for an auto-generated files or specific targets?

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively difficult to exclude specific source files from clang-tidy, because cmake generates a list of all source files of each clang-tidy activated target and passes that to clang-tidys command line.

If you enable clang-tidy only for one or more specific targets and generate your own protobuf files you can separate your protobuf stuff into a static library and not enable clang-tidy for that target. With ROS, I would advise you to only run clang-tidy on your own targets:

```
set_target_properties( myAwesomeTarget
    PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=google-*,cppcoreguidelines-"
)
```

If you want to keep the global clang-tidy, you can disable clang-tidy for single targets in the same manner:

```
set_target_properties( myAwesomeTarget
    PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to disable clang linter for an auto-generated files or specific targets?

For files, try [SKIP_LINTING](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_LINTING.html).